# Alert value of dynamically created textbox

Tags: jquery

I am creating dynamic textboxes of same class name and value like:

```
<input class='t' type='text' value='10'/>
<input class='t' type='text' value='10'/>
<input class='t' type='text' value='10'/>
```

Now I want to alert the value (10) just after the textbox creation(without any clicking or changing event)

Comment: sorry.it should be class

Comment: id can not duplicate on single DOM

Comment: where is your textbox creation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i completely understand the question, but here is a sample:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = 10;
    var name = "name";
    var inputId = "dynamicInput";

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        var input = $("<input type=\"text\" name = " + name + " id = \"dynamicInput" + i + "\" class=\"fieldname\" value=" + value + " />");
        $('#wrapper').append(input);
    }

    alert($('[name="'+ name +'"]').val());
});
```

It creates dynamically input elements, attach them to div with id "wrapper" and show the value.